# CSS3 rounded corner textbox with style

Tags: css, textbox, rounded-corners, roundedcorners-dropshadow

Im a newbie of css3, although there are a lot of css tool generators outhere, i dont't know how to code this image i provide. Kindly help please??..This will benefit my assignment on one of my major subject. Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I get only the rounded corner because i used border-radius generator tool, but i dont know howw to code the innershadow effect and that some engrave edge effect..

Comment: Copy what you have now onto http://jsfiddle.net/ and it'll be easier to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `box-shadow` multiple times:

```
box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -5px hsl(0, 0%, 40%), inset 0px 4px 6px -5px black;
```

[image]

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wUgXk/1/**

If you're on Google Chrome, open up Inspector, click on one of the values (`4px`, for instance) and press your <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys. You can tweak the values in real time and setup these kinds of effects pretty quickly.

Comment: Nice!!, Exactly the result..You saved my assignment..Thanks a lot! I will use this as referrence to learn more css3

Answer (score 5):

it's very simple in CSS to round the corners of a div use 'border-radius' CSS property on the div tag and place the image within it.

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<div id=image_box>
<img src='someimagelocation'>
</div>
```

You will then want to set the size of the dive to the exact width and height of the image and ensure that overflow is set to hidden and that your border radius property is set:

```
#image_box {
width:200px;
height:150px;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius:0.5em;
}
```

this should give you your desired result!

ADDED:

To add dropshadow etc, use the CSS property 'box-shadow' in the same div CSS tag.

```
box-shadow:0 1px 2px #aaa;
```

You will need to google how these syntax work. But I have given you all the necessary tools to research it very easily

Comment: how about the innershadow and that kind of engrave effect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css"> 
        .tbox
{
border:2px solid #b3b3b3;
background:#dddddd;
width:200px;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px; 
-moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 1px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
 box-shadow:         1px 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
}
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <input type="text" class="tbox" />

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: it does have the rounded corner but the effect (innershadow and engrave edge effect) still not

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="Your Name" style="text-align:center; color:white; background:black;  border-radius:50px; height:30;" />
<input type="email"  placeholder="Enter your email id" style="text-align:center; color:white;  background:black;  border-radius:50px 5px 50px; height:30;" />
```

Seccond textbox in Different style

Comment: The simple answer is add border-radius (style="border-radius: 5px;")